# Welcher Kasus im Adjektiv?

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective

Es gibt etwas auf Deutsch, was ich nie verstanden habe.
Wenn wir komplexe Sätze nur als Adjektiv bilden, was ist der Kasus?

Was ist richtig?

> a) Die (Nominativ) im (Dativ) Dokument dargestellte Schraube
>
> b) Die (Nominativ) im Dokument dargestellter Schraube
>
> c) Die (Nominativ) im Dokument dargestellten Schraube

Comment: Was meinst du mit »komplexe Sätze nur als Adjektiv«? Deine Beispiele sind weder Sätze (sondern Nominalphrasen), noch enthalten sie ein Adjektiv. Das Wort »dargestellt« ist das Partizip Perfekt des Verbs »darstellen«. Partizipien sind keine Adjektive.

Comment: **[Kommentare sind nicht geeignet, Antworten zu geben.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).** Falls ihr noch etwas zu sagen habt, gibt es unten eine CW-Antwort, da könnt ihr alles eintragen, was noch fehlt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ich dachte, dass »dargestellt« ein Adjektiv war, da dieses Wort dekliniert werden muss.

Comment: @Aónio: Auch Partizipien werden dekliniert, wenn sie als Attribut eines Nomens verwendet werden. Attributive Partizipien verhalten sich genau gleich wie attributive Adjektive. Aber trotzdem sind Partizipien Formen von Verben. Der Umstand, dass Partizipien gewissermaßen zwischen Verben und Adjektiven stehen kommt auch in der deutschen Bezeichnung *»Mittelwort«* gut zum Ausdruck. (Verb = Zeitwort; Adjektiv = Eigenschaftswort; Partizip = Mittelwort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Antworten aus Kommentaren:*

Antwort a) ist richtig. Kleiner Tipp: Dein Beispielsatz muss auch ohne »im Dokument« funktionieren, da der Satzteil nur genauer erklärt, wo die Darstellung erfolgt. Dann ist die Komplexität weg und du erkennst die richtige Antwort selbst. <sup>[IQV](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/25361/iqv)</sup>

Adjektive stehen immer vor dem zugehörigen Substantiv.<sup>[Janka](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/23885/janka)</sup>

Der Fall des Adjektivs richtet sich nach dem Substantiv, auf das es sich bezieht. Ein Zusatz in + Dativ ändert daran nichts. Das Partizip wird allerdings in dem Satzfragment (nennen wir’s mal so, ein vollständiger Satz ist es tatsächlich nicht) als Adjektiv verwendet.<sup>[RHA](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/26847/rha)</sup>

> Die im dargestellten Dokument dargestellte Schraube.<sup>[tofro](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/20363/tofro)</sup>

Deine Beispiele sind weder Sätze (sondern Nominalphrasen) noch enthalten sie ein Adjektiv. Das Wort »dargestellt« ist das Partizip Perfekt des Verbs »darstellen«. Partizipien sind keine Adjektive.<sup>[Hubert Schölnast](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1487/hubert-sch%C3%B6lnast)</sup>

Comment: Partizipien können als Adjektive verwendet werden, von daher schließen sich die Begriffe "Partizip" und "Adjektiv" nicht aus.

Comment: @RHa: warum baust du das nicht selbst mit einem [edit] in die Antwort ein? Mir macht das nämlich nicht wirklich Spaß. Du kannst auch gerne eine komplette Antwort schreiben, wenn Du noch mehr sagen möchtest.

Comment: Ich hätte an sich gedacht, dass kritische Anmerkungen in die Kommentare gehören. Vielleicht will Hubert Schölnast auf meine Anmerkung eingehen und seine Antwort entsprechend anpassen.

Comment: @RHa Leider hat auch Hubert keine Antwort geschrieben, unter die Du solch ein Kommentar setzen könntest, Dein Kommentar verpufft also vermutlich. Eine CW-Antwort war hier nur ein Notbehelf, nachdem viele Antworten ausschließlich in Kommentaren gegeben wurden. Du darfst aber in einem CW auch alles löschen, was nicht stimmt, oder anderweitig verbessern.#

Answer (score 0):

The entire clause becomes the subject, as indicated by the definite pronoun's case, so nominative case is correct.

Comment: but if the entire clause is the subject, why "im Dokument"? That is dative! @IQV gives a very nice and correct tip for the answer!

Comment: Thank you for the input. The subject is "Die Schraube", not the entire clause. But nominative is still the correct answer of course.